Why is there no push instruction in the PLT table?
I have written a sample C code as below
#include<stdio.h>

int foo(void);
int main()
{
    puts("Hello World");
    int x = 10;
    fprintf(stdout,"Hello World 22");
    return foo();
}

I compile it via the
gcc -shared -fpic hello_world.c -o hello_world.so 
above gcc command.
The assembly for the plt call for puts looks like as below
0000000000001070 <puts@plt>:
    1070:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1074:   f2 ff 25 9d 2f 00 00    bnd jmpq *0x2f9d(%rip)        # 4018 <puts@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    107b:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1) 

Similarly for foo()

0000000000001080 <foo@plt>:
    1080:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1084:   f2 ff 25 95 2f 00 00    bnd jmpq *0x2f95(%rip)        # 4020 <foo>
    108b:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

but the assembly looks the same.
I thought, the instructions are usually like this

jump to GOT table
push relocation identifier
jump to dynamic linker

But here it seems like it directly jumps to GLIBC. Have I understood something wrong ? or am i compiling it incorrectly ?

Is that the actual code you are compiling? There's no way that compiles since you are missing the implementation for foo, it will fail at link time.

My mistake corrected the compile statement. I had compiled it via the -shared flag both the times.

Those PLT entries are indeed interesting, but they are not jumping straight into GLIBC, they are just taking the address saved in the corresponding GOT entry. That is normal and you usually see JMP + PUSH + JMP. When the symbol is not resolved the first JMP goes to the next instruction and it does PUSH + JMP to resolve the symbol. The question still stands though, I would not expect that NOP there instead of PUSH + JMP. What distro and gcc/binutils/glibc versions are you using?

@MarcoBonelli I am using
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0 .
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
It's a Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS installed on VMWare.

I think they recently changed how the PLT is set up.  This PLT you have here is set up for eager binding.  The old style was great before there were threads, but with threads race conditions started to crop up.

@fuz I am not entirely sure, used "gcc -fpic -shared -z lazy  hello_world.c -o hello_world.so" to force it for lazy binding. Still the same result.

"it seems like it directly jumps to GLIBC" don't think you can say that from the information provided. objdump shows similar thing for the old method as well. Question is, what the dynamic linker sets the pointer to initially. You should be able to find that out using gdb.

This has to do with -fcf-protection. Ubuntu's GCC is configured with --enable-cet, which enables -fcf-protection instrumentation by default. If you compile with -fcf-protection=none you will see the "normal" PLT entries that do JMP [<got-entry>]; PUSH <idx>; JMP <pltstub>.
With -fcf-protection (also =branch or =full), an additional section is added called .plt.sec, where the actual function call stubs sit. Each stub starts with an ENDBR64 (see What does the endbr64 instruction actually do?) to mark it as a valid branching target and all JMP instructions become BND JMP (see Meaning of BND RET in x86). The PUSH <idx> instructions to push the relocation index are all in .plt, which now holds a sequence of ENDBR64; PUSH <idx>; BND JUMP <pltstub> (as you can see below).
In the "normal" case, each GOT entry is initially filled with the address of the next instruction of the corresponding PLT entry.
In the case of .plt.sec, the GOT entries are instead initially filled with .plt + <offset> where <offset> points to the corresponding sequence of ENDBR64; PUSH <idx>; BND JMP <pltstub> in .plt.
As to why this was designed like this, I am not sure. I found this perf patch that seems to give some insights about .plt.sec.

Here's how the PLT looks with -fcf-protection=none, which is what you are expecting:
Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000001020 <puts@plt-0x10>:
    1020:       ff 35 e2 2f 00 00       push   0x2fe2(%rip)        # 4008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
    1026:       ff 25 e4 2f 00 00       jmp    *0x2fe4(%rip)        # 4010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
    102c:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000001030 <puts@plt>:
    1030:       ff 25 e2 2f 00 00       jmp    *0x2fe2(%rip)        # 4018 <puts@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    1036:       68 00 00 00 00          push   $0x0
    103b:       e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmp    1020 <_init+0x20>

And here's how it looks with -fcf-protection:
Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000001020 <.plt>:
    1020:       ff 35 e2 2f 00 00       push   0x2fe2(%rip)        # 4008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
    1026:       f2 ff 25 e3 2f 00 00    bnd jmp *0x2fe3(%rip)        # 4010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
    102d:       0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
    1030:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1034:       68 00 00 00 00          push   $0x0
    1039:       f2 e9 e1 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    103f:       90                      nop
    1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1044:       68 01 00 00 00          push   $0x1
    1049:       f2 e9 d1 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    104f:       90                      nop
    1050:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1054:       68 02 00 00 00          push   $0x2
    1059:       f2 e9 c1 ff ff ff       bnd jmp 1020 <_init+0x20>
    105f:       90                      nop

Disassembly of section .plt.got:

0000000000001060 <__cxa_finalize@plt>:
    1060:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1064:       f2 ff 25 8d 2f 00 00    bnd jmp *0x2f8d(%rip)        # 3ff8 <__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    106b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

Disassembly of section .plt.sec:

0000000000001070 <puts@plt>:
    1070:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1074:       f2 ff 25 9d 2f 00 00    bnd jmp *0x2f9d(%rip)        # 4018 <puts@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    107b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

